# How to convert string to image.source in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

Encrypt.cs

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.BaseUri,@"D:\Others\Quotes\1.jpg"));
var plainString = bitmapImage;
string key = txtkey.Text;  // Key
string encryptedString = await EncryptStringHelper(plainString.ToString(), key);   // Encrypt method and get string
txbencrypt.Text = encryptedString;
```

Decrypt.cs

```
 string encryptedString = txbencrypt.Text;  // Encrypt  text
 string key = txtkey.Text;   // Same key
 string decryptedString = await DecryptStringHelper(encryptedString, key);
 imgoutput.Source = decryptedString;


    private Task<string> EncryptStringHelper(string plainString, string key)
    {
        try
        {
            var hashKey = GetMD5Hash(key);
            var decryptBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(plainString, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
            var AES = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7);
            var symmetricKey = AES.CreateSymmetricKey((IBuffer)hashKey);
            var encryptedBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(symmetricKey, decryptBuffer, null);
            var encryptedString = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(encryptedBuffer);
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return encryptedString;
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

   public Task<string> DecryptStringHelper(string encryptedString, string key)
    {
        try
        {
            var hashKey = GetMD5Hash(key);
            IBuffer decryptBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(encryptedString);
            var AES = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7);
            var symmetricKey = AES.CreateSymmetricKey((IBuffer)hashKey);
            var decryptedBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(symmetricKey, decryptBuffer, null);
            string decryptedString = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, decryptedBuffer);
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return decryptedString;
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I develop Universal windows application(UWP) then tried encrypt and decrypt to image file, but i convert image to encrypt text then i couldn't convert when i decrypt that text into image.  So how do i do that?

Comment: Are your string is `base64` string?

Comment: Yes, ex:(FXr1sQhcoFsg3fRqyTovZrUw4g0nWrJtPAuk9iQgqXjWw33IXYUyEINuJViIDUGl) this is encrypt string, but i decrypt the text it's return when i put the breakpoint in the string decryptedstring variable it's show on "windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage" so how do i convert the image.

Comment: As I understood, `decryptedString` - base64string, and you want to create image from `decryptedString`

Comment: Yes, I want like do that...

Comment: why do you want to store BitmapImage in string? Even if you have a good reason then plainString.ToString() won't work becuase it will return you "Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage" not the BitmapImage converted to string

Comment: Default method return like string. so as i follow ...

Comment: Could you please post the codes of `EncryptStringHelper` and `DecryptStringHelper`?

Comment: Yes, I posted above EncryptStringHelper and DecrptStringHelper method in Decrypt.cs

Answer (score 1):

You would want to convert your base 64 string to a byte array, and then create the ImageSource from that.

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);
if (data.caseImage.Count() > 1)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data.caseImage, 0, data.caseImage.Length);
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
            var ras = ms.AsRandomAccessStream();
            await img.SetSourceAsync(ras);
            imgCase.Source = img;
        }
```

with imgCase being a Xaml image.

in terms of initially creating the base64string you would want to do something like this:

Converting BitMapImage to ImageSource:

```
                BitmapImage bitmapCamera = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapCamera.SetSource(streamCamera);
                // Convert the camera bitap to a WriteableBitmap object, 
                // which is often a more useful format.

                int width = bitmapCamera.PixelWidth;
                int height = bitmapCamera.PixelHeight;

                WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);

                using (var stream = await capturedMedia.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    wBitmap.SetSource(stream);
                }

                imgPreview.Source = wBitmap;
```

And or a StorageFile to Base64String:

```
     byte[] fileBytes = null;
     var imageFile = *Your storageFile*;

                    mimetype = imageFile.ContentType;
                    filetype = imageFile.FileType;
                    using (IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await imageFile.OpenReadAsync())
                    {
                        fileBytes = new byte[stream.Size];
                        using (DataReader reader = new DataReader(stream))
                        {
                            await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
                            reader.ReadBytes(fileBytes);
                        }
                    }
                string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
```

Hope this helps.